# Back Button default code in android

Tags: android, android-intent, back-button

I want to back to activity that calls get intent so when i use this code app crashes,

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(0);
```

But when i pressed back button which is beside the home button, it goes to the before activity the n app won't crash. So i want to know the back button code.

Please help me

The above code works when there is no get intent.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed(){
   if(you wanto go back){
       super.onBackPressed();
   }else{
       //if you dont want to go back 
       // do what you need hear....
   }  
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
onBackPressed();
```

where u can do the same action button as back button event